# Best Workaround for Geopoint SubQuery

Tags: parse-platform

I have a class with objects that contain a geopoint type. Each object also has a boolean entitled "goodPoint".

I need to return these objects sorted from distance to user's location.
I have been using the "near" function to accomplish this.
I would also like to only grab the objects who have the boolean "goodPoint" set to "true".

I would typically use "isEqual" or "wherekey".
However, it is my understanding that parse does not support combinational queries when a geopoint query (like "near") is also used.

**What is the best workaround for effectively achieving my desired result without the use of the unsupported combinational query?**

Possible thoughts:
I would like to get all 1000 points.  I could filter out client side, but am afraid this will not be scalable in the long run as I anticipate around 10%-20% of my points to be "bad" (goodPoint=false) where worst cast case would limit me to 800 points.
I could create a "graveyard" to send bad points so that they don't list in the nearest 1000, but I'm not sure where exactly to put the points for latitude and longitude.
I could move the "bad" points to another class, but parse doesn't seem to allow you to move objects across classes.
I also could just delete the points, but I need to keep them for user feedback purposes.